# Angular safe pipe implementation to bypass DomSanitizer stripping out content

Tags: html, angular

I am using Angular 9 to load some movie by youtube api.

and I had to create a pip to allow my links to be able to work in html

here is the pipe code

```
   import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeScript, SafeStyle, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'youtube',
})
export class YoutubePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
      case 'html':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
      case 'style':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
      case 'script':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
      case 'url':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
      case 'resourceUrl':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
      default:
        throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
    }
  }
}
```

The HTML Tage which I think the problem is from:

```
<div *ngFor="let video of videos" class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
  <div class="card border-0 shadow vh-50">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={{ video.id.videoId }}" target="_blank">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" [src]="https:  //www.youtube.com/watch?v={{ video.id.videoId  | youtube }}" allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <h5 class="card-title mb-0">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={{ video.id.videoId }}"> {{ video.snippet.title }} </a>
      </h5>
      <div class="card-text text-black-50">{{ video.snippet.title.slice(0, 100) }}</div>
      <!-- <p class="card-text">{{ video.snippet.title }}</p> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can see the data loaded in the console but the problem is from the iframe tag syntax.
Can you please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first, you need to sanitize the entire url, not just the id, and if you're doing a data binding in `[ ]`s, you need to do it like this:

```
<iframe [src]="('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + video.id.videoId) | youtube : 'resourceUrl'"></iframe>
```

`{{ }}` binding is for interpolation. which would be like:

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="{{ 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + video.id.videoId }}" allowfullscreen>
```

but it won't work here. you need the input binding when marking things as safe as the return value is not actually a string, it's an object that can't be interpolated correctly.

your pipe needs a type argument,and it has to be `resourceUrl` for an iframe... you can either set a default value in the function like:

```
type: string = 'resourceUrl'
```

or you can set it in your pipe:

```
video.id.videoId  | youtube : 'resourceUrl'
```

OR... since this is only for marking youtube urls as safe, you could just get rid of the type argument to the pipe and always assume it's marking a resource url.

Comment: What i need is the second one, I tried it but does not work. I got error under {{ video.id.videoId  | youtube }} says expected 2 arguments but got 1!

Comment: you haven't fed a type argument

Comment: I added :'url' but it does not work. I still got core.js:6237 ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context ... What do you mean by  could get rid of the url parameter?

Comment: just noticed you're in angular 9, you're using an outdated method, one sec

Comment: fixed it, should be good now... need to sanitize the whole url, need the input binding and it's a  resource url

Comment: How can i do that.

Comment: the first code block in my answer is the working code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212937/discussion-between-nesreenmhd-and-bryan60).

Comment: Thank you so much It worked now. You saved my Life man. Thanks a lot.